# I want to click on an element to toggle a class being referenced on a completely unrelated element (not a child, parent or sibling)

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I want to click on an element to toggle a class being referenced on a completely unrelated element (not a child, parent or sibling)**

**For example, initially the code would look like this:**

```
<div class="persons_contacts_details glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></div>
          <div class="drop_content">
            <div class="nav_item">
              Edit
            </div>
            <div class="nav_item">
              Move to...
            </div>
            <div class="nav_item_remove">
              Remove
            </div>
          </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.drop_content {
    display: none;
}
.show {
    display: block;
    z-index: 44;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: -10px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 120px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 14px 1px #afafaf;
}
```

there can be a lot of blocks, so I do not consider the option of searching for elements by id.  T think it will be better to use getElementsByClassName.. 
But help me please to solve this problem :)
My code:

```
var menuEl = document.getElementsByClassName("persons_contacts_details");
var dropcont = document.getElementsByClassName("drop_content");

for (var i = 0; i < menuEl.length; i++) {
    menuEl[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("show"); 
    }, false);
}
```

**Thank you very much in advance!!!**

Comment: Instead of `this.classList.toggle("show")`, you can simply use `ELEMENT.classList.toggle("show")`... but I'm still not sure **exactly** what you're trying to do. Could you please clarify your intent a little further? Like which element are you trying to show?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Can you paste your complete HTML? Where is your event handler?

Comment: I would like to have a block open when clicking on the icon. there are a lot of icons and, accordingly, to use getelbyId will be inconvenient..

Comment: My event handler should be on the el with class: "persons_contacts_details"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** is a jQuery function, and doesn't apply to `.classList`; it applies directly to the element itself. In order to toggle an element with raw JavaScript, the easiest solution would be to add an **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)** to the element that performs the toggling, and make use of an `if/else` to swap the **[`style.display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** between `none` and `block`.

This can be seen in the following working example:

```js
var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")[0];

function toggle() {
  if (hidden.style.display === "none") {
    hidden.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    hidden.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="controller" onclick="toggle()">Toggle!</div>
<div class="hidden">I'm Hidden!</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: as I understand..  I have to hang it on every tag with an icon? maybe there is another solution? and thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "*icon*", but you can use a click handler and achieve the same result as `onclick`. And no worries with regards to the help; it's what we're here for! :)

Comment: **this will be enough to indicate:** `var el = document.getElementsByClassName("controller);

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
   el[i].addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
 }`

**I'm right? ))** **THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH!!))**